# SML Uncaught Exception Empty

Tags: exception, syntax-error, sml, smlnj, ml

I am quite new to SML and am trying to implement a selection sort. I am running into an uncaught empty error however and can't seem to see why.

```
fun removeMin lst =
  let
    val (m, l) = removeMin(tl lst)
  in
    if null (tl lst) then
      (hd lst, [])
    else if hd lst < m then
      (hd lst, tl lst)
    else
      (m, hd lst::l)
  end;

fun selectionSort [] = []
  | selectionSort lst =
    let
      val (m, l) = removeMin(lst)
    in
      m::selectionSort(l)
    end;
```

I would appreciate suggestions as to where my mistake is and how to fix it.

Comment: There is no base case in your recursion. `removeMin` immediately calls  `removeMin` with the tail of `lst`. Eventually `lst` will be the empty list and `tl lst` will fail with an `Empty` exception. So you have to identify when you recursion should stop and add this case to `removeMin`.

Comment: Also note that in most cases you can get rid of calls to `hd` and `tl` by using pattern matching constructions. This tremendously enhances readability.

Answer (score 1):

There is no base case in your recursion.  `removeMin` immediately
calls `removeMin` with the tail of `lst`.  Eventually `lst` will be
the empty list and `tl lst` will fail with an `Empty` exception.  So you
have to identify when you recursion should stop and add this case to
`removeMin`.

You have actually identified this base case in your function: `if null (tl lst) then (hd lst, [])`.  But this case should be checked right
before the recursive call.  By reorganising your function and getting
rid of calls to `hd` and `tl` by using pattern matching constructs
this is what I get:

```ml
fun removeMin [] = raise Empty  (* should not be called with an empty list *)
  | removeMin [x] = (x, [])     (* base case of the recursion *)
  | removeMin (x :: tl) = let
      val (m, l) = removeMin tl
  in
      if x < m
      then (x, tl)
      else (m, x :: l)
  end;

fun selectionSort [] = []
  | selectionSort lst = let
      val (m, l) = removeMin(lst)
  in
      m :: selectionSort(l)
  end;

selectionSort [3, 2, 12, 4];
```

Comment: @PsychoBunnies, a good answer has been posted. You should upvote and/or accept it.